# Order all the prime ideals of $\Bbb{R}[X]$ and list the maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-domain, local-rings

> Let $R=\Bbb{R}[X]$. I need to do the following:
>
> 1. find all prime ideals
> 2. find all maximal ideals
> 3. show containments of prime ideals
> 4. indicate the minimal prime ideal
> 5. is $R$ an integral domain
> 6. is $R$ a local ring

My idea was the following:

Let me first remark that $R$ is a PID, so every ideal can be written as $(P)$ for $P\in R$. From here we immediately can deduce that $R$ is an integral domain.

We first want to find all the maximal ideals. We know that these are all ideals $(P)$ such that $P$ is irreducible in $R$. But this are all ideals of the form $$(aX^2+bX+c)$$ for $a,b,c\in \Bbb{R}$ such that for all $z\in \Bbb{R}$ $az^2+bz+c\neq 0$. From here we can also say that $R$ is not a local ring.

Now let us talk about the prime ideals. We clearly know that all maximal ideals are also prime ideals. So we only need to check if there are more ideals which are prime but not maximal. I claim that there aren't further prime ideals. Indeed let $Q$ be not a irreducible element of $R$. So $$Q=(X-a_1)...(X-a_n)$$ for $a_i\in \Bbb{R}$. Clearly $(X-a_1)...(X-a_n)\in (Q)$ but $(X-a_i)\notin (Q)$ since $\deg(X-a_i)=1<\deg(Q)$, hence $Q$ is not prime. Thus we have seen that all prime ideals are the maximal ones.

Now we see that $(0)$ is the minimal prime ideal and I think there is no maximal prime ideal.

Is this correct like this or am I completely wrong?

Comment: 6. is $R$ an integral domain or a local ring? That's a weird question, sounds like a ring is either an integral domain or a local ring.

Comment: @WhatsUp I edited it thanks! but can you help me with the rest?

Comment: In a PID every prime ideal is maximal, so you don't have to reproduce a proof.

Comment: @uniquesolution ah okey but would my proof work? And for the rest is it correct like this?

Comment: @hardmath okey I see thanks and what is your opinion to the rest, does it looks correct or completely wrong?

Comment: If it is a PID (Principal Ideal **Domain**) then of course it follows that it is a domain...  There are such things as Principal Ideal **rings** that are not domains), though...

Comment: @hardmath sorry I don't get it.. here I was really unsure

Comment: The only prime ideal that isn't a maximal ideal is the zero ideal in the ring $\mathbb R[X]$. Does that clear up the picture?

Comment: @hardmath So you mean that all other ideals are maximal or where do you want to point?

Comment: Not every ideal is a prime ideal.  You started well by identifying the maximal ideals as the principal ideals generated by an irreducible polynomial.  In $\mathbb R[X]$ there are irreducible polynomials of degree one and of degree two.  So nail down which these are.  Then you are nearly done.

Comment: @hardmath yes so all maximal ideals are either of the form $(aX^2+bX+c)$ which has no root in $\Bbb{R}$ or of the form $(X-a)$ where $a,b,c\in \Bbb{R}$. But now I remark that all of them except the zero ideal are also prime ideals and there are no more prime ideals than that. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you've now sorted things out.  A principal ideal $(p)$ is contained in another principal ideal $(q)$ if and only if $p$ is a multiple of $q$, so identifying the nonzero prime ideals with those principal ideals generated by irreducible polynomials tells you everything about the structure of prime and maximal ideals in a PID.

Comment: @hardmath ah okey I see what you mean but then does this mean that we can order all the constant polynomials (i.e. of degree $0$), all the linear monic polynomials and all the quadratic polynomials without real roots?

Comment: I'm not sure what that ("order all the  .. polynomials") has to do with your Question (or with understanding what the exercise asks).  Perhaps you are thinking about "containment of prime ideals"?  In any case you should do what you can to improve the body of your Question.  While you have obviously spent a good bit of time on its various parts, you sometimes seem to forget the earlier progress you made, leaving me unsure what remains to be answered.

Comment: @hardmath would it be okey if we shortly discuss this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136893/discussion-between-hardmath-and-aprozz).